# pyspark 3.0 - PythonUDF Runner error whilst applying OneVsRest model

Tags: pyspark

I've been able to train a OneVsRest model, and save it.The model has 100 classes. I've managed to load the model, and currently trying to apply the model on some test data. The test data has 45 million rows.

```
test_data = spark \
    .read \
    .parquet(TEST_DATA_LOC)

ovrModel  = OneVsRestModel.load(MODEL_LOCATION)
logger.warn("loading the model from {}".format(MODEL_LOCATION))

predictions = ovrModel.transform(test_data)

@udf("double")
def getRawPredictions(vectors:Vectors):
    try:
        vectors = vectors.toArray().tolist()
        probabilities = np.exp(vectors)/(1+np.exp(vectors))
        probabilities = np.round(probabilities, decimals=3)
        probability = np.max(probabilities)
        return probability
    except:
        pass

predictions = predictions \
    .withColumn('rawPrediction', getRawPredictions('rawPrediction'))
```

However, I'm getting a PythonUDFRunner error. I'm unable to fix the issue.

```
ERROR PythonUDFRunner: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:200)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage24.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1209)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1215)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:383)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1932)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:218)
```

The traceback error is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 186, in manager
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 74, in worker
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 642, in main
    if read_int(infile) == SpecialLengths.END_OF_STREAM:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 595, in read_int
    raise EOFError
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792423/error-pythonudfrunner-python-worker-exited-unexpectedly-crashed

Comment: You might want to set the number of partitions for the dataframe, so that it won't overwhelm the memory of the python runner when sending each partition to it for udf computation

Comment: the size of the data is around 3GB, What is the memory limit for the python runner?

Comment: The data may grow to larger than 3GB because Python objects consume more memory. Try to partition your dataframe before calling the udf and see if the error still happens. You can try `df = df.partition(100)` as a starting point.