# Python worker keeps on crashing in pyspark

Tags: python, java, dataframe, pyspark

I am using Python 3.12.0, my java version is 8, and my pyspark version is 3.5. I have set my environmental variables with JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME, and HADOOP_HOME and installed winutils.exe. My code runs until the df.show() and it crashes with this error. My code is below and the error displayed is below that.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Testing PySpark Example").getOrCreate()

sample_data = [{"name": "John    D.", "age": 30},
  {"name": "Alice   G.", "age": 25},
  {"name": "Bob  T.", "age": 35},
  {"name": "Eve   A.", "age": 28}]

df = spark.createDataFrame(sample_data)

df.show()
```

This is the error that shows up.

```
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/10/26 14:10:45 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/10/26 14:10:52 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)/ 1]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 26 more
23/10/26 14:10:52 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (LAPTOP-30RQFQGR executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 26 more

23/10/26 14:10:52 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<USER>\PySparkTesting\spark_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    df.show()
  File "C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 959, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) 
(LAPTOP-30RQFQGR executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 26 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2844)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2780)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3048)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2982)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2971)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:530)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:483)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:4344)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:3326)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:4332)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4332)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:3326)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3549)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:315)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 26 more
```

Another note is that I am running this in VSCode, but this error still occurs when I run it in terminal in Pyspark.

This latter part is included, but I wanted the program to initially show it unchanged.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace

# Remove additional spaces in name
def remove_extra_spaces(df, column_name):
    # Remove extra spaces from the specified column
    df_transformed = df.withColumn(column_name, regexp_replace(col(column_name), "\\s+", " "))

    return df_transformed

transformed_df = remove_extra_spaces(df, "name")

transformed_df.show()

+---+--------+
|age|    name|
+---+--------+
| 30| John D.|
| 25|Alice G.|
| 35|  Bob T.|
| 28|  Eve A.|
+---+--------+
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62411457/3238085  << Use this python package and copy paste the python stacktrace it outputs.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error, I solved it by replacing python 3.12.1 with python 3.11.8.

Comment: Thanks, I share the same situation with you and replacing the Python version to 3.11.8 also worked for me. The error log is baffling so you save me much time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to python 3.11.8, it will resolve all the py4j exceptions and errors.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this?